# SwiftUI - Only apply blendMode to a set of views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `ZStack` with a few children. Some of those children will have `.blendMode` modifier attached to them. The `ZStack` itself sits on top of a white background view. Everything works fine when the opacity of the children is 1, but when I decrease their opacity, the blending effect will affect the opaque white background as well. I don't want that, I want the blending effect only affect the children.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [compositing groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/compositinggroup()), that may do it. You might need to have another ZStack inside your main one.